# Any way to use gridgain partitioning to do load balancing with read through caches?

Tags: gridgain

I have a load balancing use-case.  We have too much data to fit entirely in memory, but we would like to load balance it across the nodes.  The load associated with any particular key is not uniform.  Thus the load balancing should be able to balance with some weighting associated with the *work* (as opposed to most load balancing discussion which has to do with node cpu capacity and current levels of business).

The *work* in this case represents data in the backing database.  So a new work item might come in with key A, and key A is associated with 10,000 rows in the database.  Another request might come in with key B is associated with 30 rows in the database, etc.

I can't store all of the data in memory.  I can't even store all of the keys in memory.  Is there any way to apply grid gains load balancing or partitioning to optimize the *affinity* of a particular key to a particular node in the cluster?  I.e. so that all of the A requests went to one node, and all of the B to another, etc. such that the average number of *rows* per node was fairly balanced across the topology.

Comment: I really don't understand the question. What do you mean by `but instead of just counts it actually records all of the key values in memory`?

Comment: Also, GridGain open source has been donated to [Apache Ignite](https://ignite.incubator.apache.org/) project which has `Rendezvous Hashing` as default hashing implementation and also has `Fair Hashing` to guarantee absolutely equal number of partitions on every cluster member.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitriy I didn't realize you guys had switched to Rendezvous.  That certainly seems simpler.  I rewrote the question above to try and describe the use case more clearly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the question now. First of all, the affinity function in GridGain (or Apache Ignite) is pluggable and you can always plugin your own implementation, even if it's heavily based on GridGain one.

Also, it is worth noting that if you were to pick primary key for rows as your cache keys, then the distribution of data would be equal, but all related keys may not be collocated on the same server. Will this approach work?